# Modify user object and push modifications back to Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Let's say that I wanted to modify a few attributes of a user and I first created an object of the user, as seen below.

```
$user = Get-ADUser Cole -Properties *
```

Then I modify an attribute, like so:

```
$user.LockedOut = "True"
```

If I go into Active Directory and check the Locked Out status of that user, it will not have changed since I only made the changes to a local variable.

I know that I could simply use `Unlock-ADAccount`, but what if that function didn't exist? Is there a way to simply make the modifications to the $user variable and have them reflected in Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

You're not modifying the Active Directory object, you're modifying the PowerShell object that happens to contain data from Active Directory. If you want to make changes to the objects in Active Directory, you'll need to use a Set-AD* cmdlet.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would use such a cmdlet to unlock a locked out user (without using Unlock-ADAccount)?

Comment: Check out ADSI. One example you can find here, but you'll have to dig through a bit of code: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WinForm-Active-Directory-a3771370/view/Discussions#content